# Jquery load not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have got a problem with a script on a website I am developing. It works fine in Safari, Opera and Chrome, but it doesn't work in firefox.

As you click a link, I try to load the div #contain from internal links to an overlay div, which then is unhidden. All this is working fine in the browsers I have mentioned above, but it wont work in firefox, the click function just opens the link (reloads the page) as it would normally do.

Any Ideas why it does not work in Firefox? Anything that I am missing?

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    var     $ov = $('.overlay'),
        $tp = $('#transparent'),
        URL = ' ',
        siteURL = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),     
        $internal = $("a[href^='"+siteURL+"'], a[href^='/'], a[href^='./'], a[href^='../'], a[href^='#']:not('.no')"),      
        hash = window.location.hash,
        $el, $allLinks = $("a");


        $tp.hide();
        $ov.hide();


        $tp.click(function(){

            $ov.empty();
            $tp.hide();
            $ov.hide(); 

        });


        if (hash) {

            $ov.show();
            $tp.show();         
            hash = hash.substring(1);
            URL = hash + " #contain";

            $ov.load(URL);

            };

        $internal.each(function(){

            $(this).attr("href", "#" + this.pathname);

            }).click(function(){

                $tp.show();
                $ov.show();

                $el  = $(this);
                URL = $el.attr("href").substring(1);
                URL = URL + " #contain",

                $ov.load(URL);

            });
    });
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem on one of my partial views.  Try adding an alert before $ov.load(URL); and see if that works.  It did for me.  I'm still searching for why it does that and/or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing preventDefault in your click function. This tells jQuery/javascript to not follow the default action which in your case would be following wherever the link is pointing to in HREF.

Instead of

```
$tp.click(function(){
    $ov.empty();
    $tp.hide();
    $ov.hide();
});
```

It should be

```
$tp.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault;
    $ov.empty();
    $tp.hide();
    $ov.hide();
});
```

Comment: I think the click function isn't even the problem. My guess is, that the way I target internal links, is somehow not working as intended.
In other browsers, the links are updated like this:
www.website.com/#/link

But in firefox they still look like this:
www.website.com/link
So I guess there must be something wrong on that end.

Answer (score 0):

instead of 
`$tp.click(function(`

try

```
$(document).on('click','#transparent',function(event){
//do whatever you want to do
});
```

Comment: I tried it, but got the same results as before. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the default behaviour of the browser :

```
(event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```