# jQuery load function not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, load

Can anybody help me why doesn't work this jquery load function on clicking in firefox? In Chrome, Safari, Explorer works well, but firefox only load characters...

Here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#load-references").click(function(){
        $('#result-references').load('references.html');
       }); 
     });
```

I'm using lot of external javascripts like jQuery, parallax, sticky-nav, responsive-nav, nav-hash etc... Does it matter?

What am i do wrong?

Here is the site which generates this problem. The site is in dev mode:
http://vidu.hu/vidu_para/

You can find the problem  in firefox at "Referenciák" menu when click on the "Megnézem" button.

Comment: Check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452044/jquery-load-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: There's a script error while parsing this JS file - [http://vidu.hu/vidu_para/js/parallax-for-firefox.js](http://vidu.hu/vidu_para/js/parallax-for-firefox.js). It's returning some junk text. Have a look at it and correct that :)

Comment: It's a bit strange because the same JS looks good in Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#load-references").on('click', function () {
   $('#result-references').load('references.html');
});
```

or

```
$(document).on('click','#load-references',function(event){
  $('#result-references').load('references.html');
});
```

Comment: I checked the code, click event handler is invoked and a request for `references.html` is fired and response received, problem is in a js file which is rendering fine in chrome but not in FF

Answer (score 0):

There's a script error while parsing this JS file - http://vidu.hu/vidu_para/js/parallax-for-firefox.js.
File is downloading fine, response code is 200 OK, but the content of file is not valid script code. It's returning some junk text. Have a look at it and correct that :)

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I have tried before to remove that file, but ff is do the same... That script is there just to make parallax smoother in FF. I have also tried that two script below but they just don't work ...

Comment: did you try removing the `script` tag for `parallax-for-firefox-js`, you already have `parallax-js`, isn't it ? Also are you using the latest version from GitHub, they might have fixed it in recent versions

Comment: I have tried to remove almost all the javascripts from the site but it is doing the same crash. Now i take that script into an external file in this case FF doesn't load anything instead of the other browsers. Also try the codes below when not using all the scripts, but they don't work too.