# Jquery functions is not working for header. When I include header using .load() Method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using `.load()` method for common header. But I want add dropdown in header for user profile.
Always, Script not working when I use `.load()` method for includin header.

Please don't suggest me to use `PHP` to include header file. I just want to resolve why jquery is not work when we use `.load()` method.

**HTML File :-**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>How to include HTML page with jQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#header" ).load( "header.html" );
   });
  </script>
 </head> 
 <body>
  <div id='header'></div>
  <div class='content'>Content</div>
   <script src="../assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../vendor/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/script.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Header Code :-**

```
<div class="user-profile"><img class="user-pic rounded-circle" src="assets/img/user.jpg"></div>
```

**Script :-**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.user-profile').click(function(){
            alert('test')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Where does script in written?

Comment: @Emanuele Script is written in script.js, external file

Comment: Then I thinks that the problem is that, when it starts, $( "#header" ).load( "header.html" ); is not already finished

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this:
Set a name for the function

```
<script>
function f()
{
    $('.user-profile').click(function(){
        alert('test')
    });
};
```

Then call the function on when load is finished like this:

```
$( "#header" ).load( "header.html", function() {
   f();
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21452044/jquery-load-not-working-in-firefox